# Ensure that a method of a class is called after every method call of the same class, how?

Tags: java, aspect-oriented

I have twenty small methods (`m1`, `m2`, `m3`, etc..) in a class quite different between each other, and after every method i would like to do some common actions, like increasing some counters and in the case write those counters to a file. Let's call those actions `ACT`.

I know that I can create a method that does `ACT`, but then I need to call it from every other method. That is, from `m1` I should call ACT as last method, from `m2` I should call `ACT` as last method, and so on.

Is there a way to say "if someone call this list of methods of this class (i.e: `m1`, `m2`, `m3` ...), please after that call that method (i.e: ACT) automatically" ? Because AFAIK is not possible.

Comment: see also: [Are certain problems solved more elegantly with AOP?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/19260/31260)

Answer (score 3):

AOP is good approach to solve your problem.

But I advice you to examine your class. Twenty small methods quite different between each other in a class is a little code smell. I think your class probably violate single responsibility principle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I would like to add to this and point out the Command Pattern, you can use this pattern with some interfaces to implement an AOP approach. This is geared towards C# but I am sure you could translate the knowledge fairly easy. https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91

Comment: Thanks for the links, my comment could be misleading.

Depends on the "amount" of difference. For me could be, for example, that method1 write to a file only integers, method2 only strings, method3 only certain objects and so on, and after all i would like to count how many changes on the file were done (for example).

But still i tried to keep the question abstract, one problem that i realize always late is that if i don't specify the question as "abstract" explicitly then details are important for who answers.